# Rules Loop does not fully loop through checked taxonomies

Tags: taxonomy-terms, rules

I have a content type that has a field which references my Country taxonomy. The field settings are set to unlimited so it is displayed as checkboxes.
The country field is also displayed on the users profile so they can choose which country they are from.

What I want is to be able to choose several countries on my new node and then have rules send an email to all the users who have those countries set on their user account.

What I have so far is:

```
Loop: Node: Country field
 Fetch data by property: user/user country field/current list item:tid
 Loop: Fetched data
   Send email to the user
```

Unfortunatly it only seems to register the first taxonomy in the list and send the email. I cant seem to work out why the loop stops after the first taxonomy.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please include an export of your rule in your question. That may help to understand your current Rule ...